# Safari Developer Menu Disabled

Tags: safari, menu-bar

Why would my "Show Safari Develop menu" option be grayed out and not clickable? I've tried to find steps to enable it, but they all simply say click on the checkbox. Do I need to log in and change permission settings somewhere?

Safari Version 13.1.2 (14609.3.5.1.5) running on a Macbook Air
macOS Mojave version 10.14.6 (18G6020)

[image]

Comment: It this your personal **MacBook Air** or does it belong to your employer?

Comment: Testing on a clean built **macOS Mojave** 10.14.6 with all updates, I found **Safari**  13.1.2 had no issues with showing the **Develop** _menu_. That said, if this is your employers **Mac** and managed by **IT** it might be intentionally disabled.

Comment: It's my personal computer. I don't see any updates I haven't applied. I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Also, the Option-Command-C shortcut has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Testing under a fully updated **macOS Mojave 10.14.6** with **Safari 13.1.2** when toggling the **Show Develop menu in menu bar** *checkbox* at **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced**, there are two **PLIST** *files* that get modified. One *file* having one *key* modified and the other *file* having three *keys* modified, i.e.:

- **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker.plist**

  - **ShowDevelopMenu**
- **~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist**

  - **IncludeDevelopMenu**
  - **WebKitDeveloperExtrasEnabledPreferenceKey**
  - **WebKitPreferences.developerExtrasEnabled**

The *value* of all four of these *keys* are a *boolean*, and when the **Show Develop menu in menu bar** *checkbox* is checked, the *value* is *yes*, *true* or *1* depending on how one is reading the settings.

In **Terminal** the `defaults read ...` *command* will return `1` or `0`, or if the *key* isn't present it errors out with a message.

The *example* **shell script** *code*, further below, was tested and works under normal circumstances, however, it may not work on an inactive **Show Develop menu in menu bar** *checkbox*. That said, you really have nothing to loose but a few minutes of time giving it a try.

**Notes:**

- **Important!** In order for this *example* **shell script** to work you'll need to, at least temporarily, add **Terminal** to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**, and **Terminal** should be closed when you do.
- When the *example* **shell script** is run, **Safari** should be closed as well, however, *as coded* it will close it if it's open. It will also open it after the changes have been made.
- Because of other **OS** security measures, (*sandboxing*), the **com.apple.Safari.plist** *file* needs be copied to `/tmp/`, modified there, and then moved back. The **shell script**, *as coded*, handles this. The **com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker.plist** *file* is modified in place.
- As coded, the two **PLIST** *files* get backed up with a **.bak** *extension*, however the **shell script** can only be run one time unless the `n` is removed from `cp -avn` for both *files*, which will then **overwrite the original backups**!
- As coded, it will output debugging information (`set -x`) and this is in case you have an issue you can copy and paste the *output* from **Terminal** for troubleshooting if need be. So, if there is an issue, do not close the *window* until it's copied and pasted elsewhere so I can see it.

To use the *example* **shell script** *code*:

1. Open **Terminal** and run the following *compound command*:

   ```
   touch sdmcb; chmod u+x sdmcb; open -e sdmcb
   ```
2. Copy and paste the *example* **shell script** *code* into the opened **sdmcb** *document*, then save and close it.
3. Back in **Terminal** use the following *command* to run the **shell script**:

   ```
   ./sdmcb
   ```

That's it, this will either work or it won't, it's the only thing I can think of trying, sans booting to **macOS Recovery** and deleting the two **PLIST** *files* which may remove a setting that's causing it to be inactive to begin with, if it's even in those two *files*.

---

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

[[ $(ps x | grep '[S]afari.app') == ""  ]] || killall Safari; sleep 2
cd "$HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/" || exit
cp -v 'com.apple.Safari.plist' '/tmp/' || exit
cp -avn 'com.apple.Safari.plist' 'com.apple.Safari.plist.bak' || exit
defaults write '/tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist' "IncludeDevelopMenu" -bool 'yes'
defaults write '/tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist' "WebKitDeveloperExtrasEnabledPreferenceKey" -bool 'yes'
defaults write '/tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist' "WebKitPreferences.developerExtrasEnabled" -bool 'yes'
mv -v '/tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist' .
cd "$HOME/Library/Preferences/" || exit
cp -avn 'com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker.plist' 'com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker.plist.bak' || exit
defaults write "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker.plist" "ShowDevelopMenu" -bool 'yes'
killall cfprefsd
sleep 3
open -a "/Applications/Safari.app"
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your work on this. I'll try it out soon.

Comment: Did not work for me. The script completed, but the setting was still grayed out. Using Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here - in Big Sur

No terminal use / shell script use

I manually removed all safari settings / cache / preference files

https://macissues.com/2015/06/22/how-to-fully-reset-safari-on-your-mac/

Reinstalled Mac OS .

can now check "Show Develop "